# Cannot write log to file using log4j2.properties in log4j ver 2.13.3 or higher

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2 in a Spring project. My below config worked fine for log4j2 version 2.6.1, but when I change the version to 2.13.3 or 2.14.1 (the latest version) all the logs get printed to the console instead of the log file. Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Here is my log4j2.properties config

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = C:\\logs\\debug.log

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = C:\\logs\\Previous\\debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 100000
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = com.example.demo
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

My application file

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringLog4j2Application {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SpringLog4j2Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringLog4j2Application.class, args);
        
        System.out.println("Hello log4j2");
        LOGGER.debug("This is debug statement");
        LOGGER.info("This is info log");
        LOGGER.warn("This is warn log");
        LOGGER.error("This is error log", new NullPointerException());
        LOGGER.fatal("This is a fatal log");
        LOGGER.trace("This is trace log");
    }

}
```

And my pom.xml

```
    ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Log4J2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-log4j2</name>
    <description>Demo Spring Boot project for Log4j2</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so it seems like we have to exclude some new jar, coming with the newer log4j versions. We can do this by adding these lines to our pom.xml

```xml
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

So my new pom.xml will look like this

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <!-- HERE ARE THE NEW LINES -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```